# Does removing liquidity from a staked pancakeswap lp unstake it?

Tags: pancakeswap, uniswapv3, liquidity-provider, staking, amm

If I remove all the liquidity from a PancakeSwap V3 LP, I know it also collect the fees earned.

But if that LP is staked in a farm, will removing the liquidity automatically unstake it and harvest the rewards?